# Warum gibt es auf dieser Affische aus 1949 über jeden Buchstabe "U" einen art Makron?

Tags: spelling, typography

Auf dieser Affische aus 1949 sind die Wörter *Schlußstrich*, *drunter*, und *Schluss* geschrieben als ob es eine Makron über den Buchstabe *u* gibt:

[image: Poster aus 1949 mit u.a. dem Text "Schlūßstrich drunter!*]

Die kursiv geschriebene *u*-Buchstaben scheinen eine Makron zu haben: *Schlūßstrich* (*), Schlūss (*), und *drūnter* (*).  Der ungeübte leser könnte diese mit Umläute tauschen.  War oder sogar ist es im Kursiv gangbar der Buchstabe *u* so zu schreiben?

*([Quelle für Affische](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/53662/130))*

Comment: Related, in English: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52107/was-the-u-with-breve-of-kurrent-and-s%c3%bctterlinschrift-ever-used-in-print

Comment: Es war/ist auf jeden Fall mal üblich gewesen, um es vom "n" abzugrenzen. Ob das hier der Fall ist weiß ich aber nicht.

Comment: Meine Mutter hat noch in den 50er/60er Jahren in der Schule gelernt, die handschriftlichen "u"s mit einem Strich drueber zu schreiben und schreibt es auch heute noch so, aus dem Grund, den infinitezero nennt. Fuer mich ist das absolut nichts Ungewoehnliches, auch wenn ich es nicht so gelernt habe.

Comment: I am still doing it when handwriting. Originally it came from the Sütterlin lettering to distinguish from _e_ (@infinitezero)..

Comment: Hat nichts mit der Frage zu tun, aber es ist interessant, dass die (damalige) FDP in der Absicht, einen Schlussstrich unter die NS-Zeit zu ziehen, das Wort "Schluß" (nach alter Rechtsschreibung mit "ß" zu schreiben) zweimal mit "ss" schreibt. In meinen Augen ähnelt die Buchstabengruppe "ss" auf  dem Plakat schon ein wenig den berüchtigten Runen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Eher, um es vom Sütterlin-*n* abzugrenzen, das sonst identisch wäre. Das Sütterlin-*e* hingegen ist schmaler und hat einen Querstrich, der in der oberen Hälfte statt unten ansetzt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ein solches Häklein über dem u war in Handschriften jener Zeit gängige Praxis. Da die Kursive eine Art "angedeutete Handschrift" in der Druck-Typographie ist, hat der Schriftstecher hier das handschriftliche u-Häklein in seine Typen mit aufgenommmen.

Zur Genese des u-Strichs: Es dient zur Unterscheidung des u vom n, die in bestimmten Handschriftenformen sehr ähnlich aussehen können, und in der Sütterlinschrift auch zur Unterscheidung vom ansonsten gleichgeformten e.<sup>1</sup>

Hier das Sütterlin-Alphabet. Man vergleiche e, m, n und u.

[image]

Beachte auch, dass ein waagrechter, gerader Strich (im Gegensatz zum suppenschüsselförmigen u-Häkchen) zur Verdopplung eines Konsonanten dient.

---

<sup>1</sup>Ein krasses Beispiel der Ununterscheidbarkeit von Buchstaben in Handschrift, weil nur noch eine Auf-ab-Zackenlinie zu sehen ist, gibt der gegenwärtige (2020) amerikanische Präsident mit einer Unterschrift.

Comment: Witzig ist auch, dass man daran sieht, wie sich der heutige Umlaut entwickelt hat. Er ist nämlich ein hochgestelltes "e" über dem jeweiligen Buchstaben.

Comment: Noch zu meiner Schulzeit (um 1980 herum) haben einige Lehrer den u-Strich verwendet, obwohl er in der lateinischen Schreibschrift überflüssig ist.

Comment: Die Genese im Sinn eines Ursprung, und nicht eines Zwecks liegt in einem ursprünglichen UO, das mit hochgestelltem O als Ů geschrieben wurde. Die Schreibung Ů blieb erhalten, auch nachdem der Laut UO mit normalem U zusammengefallen war – genauso wie beim IE.

Comment: Das Sütterlin-*e* unterscheidet sich in den zwei Punkten deutlich vom -*n*, dass der Querstrich in der Mitte statt unten ansetzt und es maximal etwa halb so breit ist wie letzteres (oft noch schmaler geschrieben, das *n* immer breit). Bei präziser Schreibweise besteht somit auch ohne Haken keinerlei Verwechslungsgefahr mit _n_ oder _u_.